# Post to wall as Facebook Application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

The below code works fine but the issue it posts as the user ( $post_user_id ). I want it to post as the application. Show application name and application icon as display picture on the post. Something similar to the example in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ => https://www.facebook.com/platform/posts/10150189643478553

```
 $args = array(
    'access_token'  => "".$array['accesstoken']."",
    'message'       => "".$message."",
    'link'          => "http://www.example.com/",
        'from'          => "application id",
    'to'            => "".$post_user_id."",
    );
$post_id = $facebook->api("/$post_user_id/feed","post",$args);
```

Answer (score 1):

use FACEBOOK PHP SDK 
and this code to post on user wall

```
<?php
$status="anything you want to post";
$facebook_id=$userdata['id'];
$params = array('access_token'=>$access_token, 'message'=>$status);
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$facebook_id/feed";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use facebook 'Actions' to post as the application.
When you post an action it says something like
'Saad commented on this article at example.com'
The words article and example.com will be hyperlinks back to your site.

View the documentation on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/customopengraph/walkthrough/

Comment: Thank you for the link! Something i didn't about before and will surely be helpful in the future. But this isn't exactly what i am searching for at the moment. In simple words i want to make a post on users wall like in this example https://www.facebook.com/platform/posts/10150189643478553 << This post is made by Facebook Platform. So similarly i want a post on Users Wall which says MyApp123

Comment: This is done via actions, you wont achieve this 'effect' posting to a wall. You should look into the Graph API.